# How does one process the results from replicate in R?

Tags: r

Say I have the following code which essentially gives me random simulations for revenue and cost for 12 months

```
simulate.revenue<-function() {
  return(sapply(rnorm(12,100000,30000),function(x) max(0,x)))
}
simulate.cost<-function() {
  return(sapply(rnorm(12,50000,20000),function(x) max(0,x)))
}

sim.run<-function() {
  revenue<-simulate.revenue()
  cost<-simulate.cost()
  profit<-revenue-cost
  year.simulation<-data.frame(revenue,cost,profit)
  return(year.simulation)
}
```

Now to run the above simulation function 10 times I am aware that I should:

```
sim.results<-replicate(10,sim.run())
```

So the question is how do I further process sim.results to say:

1. find the mean for total yearly profit over each run
2. find the mean for profit by month over each of the runs (mean(profit[1], mean(profit[2]), ...)

Comment: definitely `replicate`

Comment: thanks :-) I'll take a look

Comment: @RichardBorder hi Richard, I read about replicate and was able to apply it -- still researching how to process the result of replication -- modified the question to reflect that.

Comment: Look at `ColMeans` and `RowMeans`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Structure of replicate result:**

`replicate(1, sim.run())` easily gives you the structure of what is returned: A list item for each column of the data.frame (here 3 list items). Running two simulations adds another 3 list items.

**Convert it into proper format:**

To convert the `list` into a `data.frame` use:

```
result <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(sim.results), nrow = 12, byrow = FALSE))
```

In your case every 3 columns of the resulting `data.frame` correspond to one simulation. To separate the simulations into a list again:

```
result_list <- list()
m <- 1
n_simulations <- 10
n_columnsPerSimulation <- 3
for (i in seq(1, n_simulations * n_columnsPerSimulation, n_columnsPerSimulation)){
    result_list[[m]] <- result[,seq(i, i+n_columnsPerSimulation-1)]
    m <- m + 1
}
```

This is very ugly but seems to work.

**Analyze result:**

Now you can analyze each simulation e.g. with sapply/lapply like the following example shows:

```
sapply(result_list, function(x) mean(x[,1]))
```